# How do i unload UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

is there a better way than this? The loadRequest in the killWebView method is a hack to get rid of webPages like youtube.  I dont want to do it like that, but i cannot find any documentation on how to unload the WebView...

```
- (IBAction)killWebView:(id)sender 
{
[self.webView stopLoading];
[self.webModal setHidden:YES];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}

- (IBAction)viewVideoLink:(id)sender 
{
 self.webModal.backgroundColor = [self randomColor:.4];
[self.webModal setHidden:NO];    
NSString *strWebsiteUlr = [NSString stringWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",   [self.model.currentTrackDictionary objectForKey:@"video_url"]]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strWebsiteUlr];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are releasing self.webView, then two lines later, you're sending a message to self.webView.  That will cause a crash.

Comment: Thanks - i removed those 2 lines and it works but im wondering if there is a better way? the html file is just a basic html file that says "content loading"  seems like there should be a better way to do it.